# RichTextBox use to retrieve Text property in C++

Tags: unicode, richtextbox

I am using a hidden RichTextBox to retrieve Text property from a RichEditCtrl.
**rtb->Text**; returns the text portion of either **English** of **national** languages – just great!

But I need this text in \u12232? \u32232? instead of national characters and symbols.  to work with my db and RichEditCtrl.  Any idea how to get from “**пассажирским поездом Невский**” to “**\u12415?\u12395?\u23554?\u20219?\u30456?\u35527?\u21729?** (where each national character is represented as “\u23232?”

If you have, that would be great.
I am using visual studio 2008 C++ combination of MFC and managed code.

Cheers and have a wonderful weekend

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `System::String` as an output as well, then something like this would do it:

```
String^ s = rtb->Text;
StringBuilder^ sb = gcnew StringBuilder(s->Length);
for (int i = 0; i < s->Length; ++i) {
    sb->AppendFormat("\u{0:D5}?", (int)s[i]);
}
String^ result = s->ToString();
```

By the way, are you sure the format is as described? `\u` is a traditional Escape sequence for a *hexadecimal* Unicode codepoint, exactly 4 hex digits long, e.g. `\u0F3A`. It's also not normally followed by `?`. If you actually want that, format specifier `{0:X4}` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks Pavel. I will try your suggestion tonight.
As for the format, those \u12395?\u23554? etc. are UNICODE hex as you correctly pointed out. I cut and pasted an example from my debug output - so the "?"  really follows the \u with 5 or 3 digits depending on language.

Whare are you from?

Comment: If they are hex, there shouldn't be 5 digits in them, as `\u` only permits four (and requires exactly four) in C++ and C#. What "debug output" did you cut?

Comment: Pavel you are write about the 5 digits for asian languages like Chinese (\u20219?\u30456?\u35527?) or Russian (\u1086?\u1084?\u1099?) in my example above.  As I get from Greek, it's seems only 3 digits available as here: "\u957? \u946?\u959?" All of my examples are snippets only not full sentences.
I am having the very first project in internaltional languages and having lots of fun;-) I am just back from University after having a long day and a few beers.  I'll try the stuff tomorrow on a fresh head.  Privet

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use escaping to put formatted Unicode in a RichText control.  You can use UTF-8.  See my answer here: [Unicode RTF text in RichEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782409/unicode-rtf-text-in-richedit/1782460#1782460).

I'm not sure what your restrictions are on your database, but maybe you can use UTF-8 there too.

Comment: Wow, great answer article!  If I got it right, your PSTR Utf8; will look like "\u12395?\u23554?\u20219?" when PWSTR WideString = "Сотрудники главного управления МЧС ".
Am I correct?

Comment: The way UTF-8 works, each WCHAR value that is > 128 will be represented as anywhere from 2 to 4 CHAR values...  For example L"д" will be "\xd0\xb4".  You can read more about how it works at the Wikipedia article for UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks again buddy, you've helped a lot.  Cheers, I need a break after a party with my friends at universcity tonight.  I'll try to fix my code tomorrow ;-)