# Windowless RichEdit Controls cannot enter emoji

Tags: c++, mfc

When I use `Windowless RichEdit Controls`(`ITextHost`, `ITextServices`), I found that if I enter an emoji such as , it will become □.

And if I use `CreateWindowEx` to create a `RICHEDIT50W`, all emoji is correct. But if create a `RICHEDIT20W`, enter emoji will become □.

Is Windowless RichEdit create `RICHEDIT20W`? How can I use Windowless RichEdit to create `RICHEDIT50W`?

Comment: Emojis have high code points in Unicode and are probably missing in most other encodings. Without knowing details, I would suspect that `RICHEDIT20W` doesn't use any flavor of Unicode encoding or uses a font which hasn't glyphs for the code points in quest. My reading hint: [Minimum about Encodings](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: I googled [richedit20w unicode](https://www.google.com/search?q=richedit20w+unicode) and found (among others) the following which might be of interest: [SO: Unicode RTF text in RichEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782460/7478597).

Comment: Can you enter this emoji in Notepad? Some Windows versions may not have the fall back font.

Comment: I enter into notepad and emoji is correct. I use spy++ and I guest notepad is use RICHEDIT50W.

Comment: If I enter emoji, it will be incorrect, but if I use EM_SETTEXTEX, emoji can display correctly.(RICHEDIT20W)

Comment: RichEdit20W is, is, is Unicode.  That is what the W at the end of the class name signifies.

Comment: Please show [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can use `ITextServices` from `msftedit.dll` which is RichEdit 4.1 at least (depending on OS version). This is explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/about-windowless-rich-edit-controls).

Comment: I have used ITextServices from msftedit.dll

Answer (score 1):

Having the same question,  fixed by setting the font to "segeo UI Emoji"